# How can I group html objects on this Jquery focus call?

Tags: html, jquery

How can I group textarea and input as shown on this piece of example:

```js
$("textarea:invalid").first().focus();
$("input:invalid").first().focus();
```

I want to write it in a single line, tried with

```js
$("input, textarea:invalid").first().focus();
```

without results...

Comment: `$("input:invalid, textarea:invalid").first().focus();`

Comment: Can u define group? On what do you want to focus?

Comment: In the end only _one_ element can receive the focus. To my knowledge it is impossible to have _two cursors_ active in _two input fields_.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann that's what the `first()` is for :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the approach you're using would be:

```js
$("input:invalid, textarea:invalid").first().focus();
```

Note the `:invalid` psuedo-selector added to `input`.

However it's worth noting that jQuery has another selector you can use which will select all form controls, `:input`. This may be better suited to your specific use case:

```js
$(':input:invalid').first().focus();
```